# Dynamically loading content through Groovy server page upon form submit

Tags: forms, web, groovy, gsp

I have a Groovy project (vanilla; no Grails) with an `index.gsp` that takes form input from the user and sends it in a POST request to a Groovy script. The form is set up like this:

```
<form action="somewhere" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    // some other inputs
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Is there any way (ideally not using Javascript) to dynamically load content on the same page after the user submits? Redirecting to another GSP might also work. Just something simple, like a string containing whatever the user typed. It seems like Grails has plenty of options, but unfortunately I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, Grails is capable of doing what you need without any complex code. Since you can't use it, you will have to use JQuery(Javascript) to make an AJAX call. AJAX is the he only way that I know to achive that.

Just make an AJAX call to your groovy script. JQuery.ajax has a *success* function to be called if the request succeeds. You can use it to update a hidden dive after the form. This success function has the data returned from the server as an argument, that data could be the string containing whatever the user typed. In that case just add the data to the hidden div and then make that div visible.

```
function onSucceed(data) {
   $('#hiddenDivToUpdate').text(data);
   $('#hiddenDivToUpdate').show();
}
```

You can learn about JQuery.ajax() in this link [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)